# Compare sums of elements in an array: Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting

I need to check whether the sum of any 2 elements of an array equals to the given number. This is what I came up with, but it doesn't seem to do the comparison

```
def sum_comparison(int_array, x)
  n = int_array.length
  (0..n).each do |i|
    (1..n).each do |j|
      if ((int_array[i].to_i + int_array[j].to_i) == x)
        return true
      else
        return false
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The code I posted doesn't seem to work correctly, I need someone to hint where is the mistake

Comment: How is `sum_comparison` used? What is `int_array_length`?

Comment: I don't understand problem description. You want to see if sum of two-element array is equal to something or that any two elements sum up to, or what etc?

Comment: The array may have any number of elements, not obligatory 2. I need to check if sum of any 2 elements of the array equals to some number(I pass the number as the second parameter to the method and the number maybe any as well. Does it make it clear?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your solution seems overly complicated and strongly influenced by the programming style of low-level procedural languages like C. One apparent problem is that you write

```
n = int_array.length
(0..n).each do |i|
  # use int_array[i].to_i inside the loop
end
```

Now inside the `each` loop, you will get the numbers `i = 0, 1, 2, ..., n`, for example for `int_array = [3,4,5]` you get `i = 0, 1, 2, 3`. Notice that there are four elements, because you started counting at zero (this is called an off by one error). This will eventually lead to an array access at `n`, which is one beyond the end of the array. This will again result in a `nil` coming back, which is probably why you use `to_i` to convert that back to an integer, because otherwise you would get a `TypeError: nil can't be coerced into Fixnum` whend doing the addition. What you probably wanted instead was simply:

```
int_array.each do |i|
  # use i inside the loop
end
```

For the example array `[3,4,5]` this would actually result in `i = 3, 4, 5`. To get the combinations of an array in a more Ruby way, you can for example use `Array#combination`. Likewise, you can use `Array#any?` to detect if any of the combinations satisfy the specified condition:

```
def sum_comparison(array, x)
  array.combination(2).any? do |a, b|
    a + b == x
  end
end
```

Comment: Is there any reason to use permutation rather than combination? The latter is a subset of the former, and is enough to be considered.

Comment: @sawa you are correct, `combination` is better since it will yield less results and thus terminate faster when the condition is not met. The order is irrelevant because integer addition is commutative.

Answer (score 5):

When your function compare first element, it's immediately returns false. You need to return only true when iterating and return false at the end if nothing were found, to avoid this issue:

```
def sum_comparison(int_array, x)
  n = int_array.size
  (0...n).each do |i|
    (1...n).each do |j|
      if (int_array[i].to_i + int_array[j].to_i) == x
        return true
      end
    end
  end
  false
end
```

To simplify this you can use [`permutation`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-permutation) or [`combination`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-combination) and [`any?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F) methods as @p11y suggests. To get founded elements you  could use [`find` or `detect`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-find).

```
def sum_comparison(a, x)
  a.combination(2).any? { |i, j| i + j == x }
end

a.combination(2).detect { |i, j| i + j == x }
# sum_comparison([1,2,3, 4], 6) => [2, 4]
```

Comment: Small comment on the first (long) solution: You will always go through all elements, you could `return true` when a match was found and just write `false` at the end of the method. This allows you to terminate early. Your suggestion of using `detect` is very useful.

Answer (score 3):

Using an enumerator:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

def sum_comparison(int_array, x)
  enum = int_array.to_enum
  loop do
    n = enum.next
    enum.peek_values.each do |m|
      return true if (n + m) == x
    end
  end
  false
end

puts sum_comparison([1, 2, 3, 4], 5)
```

Output:

```
true
```

Comment: Why should this be more efficient?

Comment: @p11y Just my thoughts actually sorry. At least I find it easier to portray.

Comment: My point is that while your code is correct, you are only using a lower level API to accomplish the same thing. Your code will not terminate earlier or something. However I have a problem with it because it introduces more syntactic noise.

Comment: @p11y I see. That's basically a matter of taste. Actually, if `Enumerator#peek_values` is programmatically optimized that element pointers are not reproduced, the form should be faster than anything that reproduces sets of elements. Only thing is that I don't have the time to look at Ruby's code yet.

Comment: If you've started as a coder in C who cared much about optimization you'd comprehend what I mean. Those who started with interpreted languages tend to only care about readability.

Comment: I have written C and C++ and I know what you mean. However I think it is wrong to assume that something is faster because you use a lower level API. I don't think it is a matter of taste, because the point of using Ruby is to have a concise and expressive high-level syntax and not having to worry about low level details. If you need raw performance, Ruby is the wrong choice anyway. By the way `Array#combination` is implemented in C - it doesn't get more efficient than that in Ruby: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/b5e89e44f12a6e3a42e9515d1d3705d11f9442bf/array.c#L4962-L4992

Comment: @p11y I didn't write it just because it's a lower API. I find it easier to use than calculating bulky indices. Of course `Array#combination` is written in C just like most parts of the core. That's not surprising. But you can imagine `malloc()` for every set made. Yes, Ruby is the wrong choice for performance and is meant to be expressive but things such as these are not that difficult either. It wouldn't hurt giving it a little speed when needed than completely migrating to another language. And I'm not all into speed. I balance readability and efficiency. It's not a difficult practice.

Comment: By the way I didn't know that using `Array#combination` can be a solution before I posted this so I could have considered using it over an Enumerator. But if you want to compare the original solution over this, I'd choose this.

Comment: Ok maybe I was too specific there, but I still see no advantage over just using a simple nested `each`.

Comment: @p11y Well one thing, I hate redundancy. Clearly the original solution compares a pair more than once. Check it. Forget about efficiency. It's just programmatically wrong.

Comment: that's right. I actually got that wrong at first too, because I used `permutation` instead of `combination`. Don't get me wrong, all I am saying is that your solution is not very idiomatic and I don't really see the benefit of using iterators. It may just be the wrong kind of advice to give to a beginner looking for a simple solution.

Comment: [Kernel#loop](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-loop) rescues the `StopIteration` exception by breaking the loop. You therefore don't need the `begin..rescue..end` block.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**

Your method is equivalent to:

```
def sum_comparison(int_array, x)
  return int_array[0].to_i + int_array[1].to_i == x
end
```

Therefore,

```
int_array = [1,2,4,16,32,7,5,7,8,22,28]
sum_comparison(int_array, 3) #=> true, just lucky!
sum_comparison(int_array, 6) #=> false, wrong!
```

**Alternative**

Here is a relatively efficient implemention, certainly far more efficient than using `Enumerable#combination`.

**Code**

```
def sum_comparison(int_array, x)
  sorted = int_array.sort
  smallest = sorted.first
  sorted_stub = sorted.take_while { |e| e+smallest <= x }
  p "sorted_stub = #{sorted_stub}"
  return false if sorted_stub.size < 2
  loop do
    return false if sorted_stub.size < 2
    v = sorted_stub.shift
    found = sorted_stub.find { |e| v+e >= x }
    return true if found && v+found == x
  end
  false
end
```

**Examples**

```
sum_comparison([7,16,4,12,-2,5,8], 3)
  # "sorted_stub = [-2, 4, 5]"
  #=> true
sum_comparison([7,16,4,12,-2,5,8], 7)
  # "sorted_stub = [-2, 4, 5, 7, 8]"
  #=> false
sum_comparison([7,16,4,22,18,12,2,41,5,8,17,31], 9)
  # "sorted_stub = [2, 4, 5, 7]"
  #=> true
```

**Notes**

- The line `p "sorted_stub = #{sorted_stub}"` is included merely to display the array `sorted_stub` in the examples.
- If `e+smallest > x` for any elements `f` and `g` in `sorted` for which `g >= e` and `f < g`, `f+g >= e+smallest > x`. Ergo, `sorted_stub.last` is the largest value in `sorted` that need be considered.
- For a given value `v`, the line `found = sorted_stub.find { |e| v+e >= x }` stops the search for a second value `e` for which `v+e = x` as soon as it finds `e` such that `v+e >= x`. The next line then determines if a match has been found.